# Given the following quadrilateral, prove $AB = BC$

Tags: geometry

> Given quadrilateral $ABCD$ such that $\angle A = 160°$, $\angle B = 80°$, $\angle C = 80°$, $\angle D = 40°$ and such that $DA = AB$, prove that $AB = BC$.

Comment: Where did you come across this problem, and what exactly is your difficulty solving it?

Comment: @MikePierce I'm trying to solve this puzzle here: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29623/the-adventitious-18-gon. Sketching it out I get http://i.stack.imgur.com/9Zxpj.png. I already easily see that the triangle is isosceles and therefore the side length is equal to the intersection. And my guess was that if I solve this problem also, I solved the puzzle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem/settings:
[image]
You can take a look at [this site](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/80-80-20/IndexToClassical.shtml), for example, Solution 12.

For completeness, here's a hint: rotate $B$ around $E$ by $60^\circ$, call it $C^\prime$. Then $\triangle C^\prime BC$ and $\triangle BED$ are congruent because $\angle C^\prime BC=\angle BED =20^\circ$, $\angle BC\prime C=\angle EBD=10^\circ$, and $BE=C^\prime B$.

[image]

Comment: I took me a couple of minutes to realize why $\angle C^\prime BC = 20°$ but I finally got it :) thanks!